# Dplyr to count means by group and then quantiles for each

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, quantile

I have a problem with dplyr, or I just can't figure out how to code the quantile-part right.

I have a data that i want to group by X and Y, then count the means for a in each group

```
dmean %>%
  group_by(x,y) %>%
   summarise(mean=mean(a))
```

This part works, no problem.
How do i continue the code to get the lowest 10% and highest 10% percentile of each group?

Comment: did you try `quantile(a, 0.1)` and `quantile(a, 0.9)`?

Comment: `dmean %>%
      group_by(sp, ika11) %>%
      summarise(mean=mean(e2)) %>%
      quantile(e2, 0.1)`
 
gIves me error code: Error: Unsupported use of matrix or array for column indexing

Comment: `summarize(mean=mean(e2), q10=quantile(e2, 0.1), q90=quantile(e2, 0.9))`

Comment: Thanks, this works!

Answer (score 3):

You can put several expressions inside `summarise`, as so:

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl, am) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(mpg),
            quantile_10 = quantile(mpg, 0.1),
            quantile_90 = quantile(mpg, 0.9))
# A tibble: 6 x 5
# Groups:   cyl [?]
    cyl    am     mean quantile_10 quantile_90
  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     4     0 22.90000       21.76       24.08
2     4     1 28.07500       22.38       32.85
3     6     0 19.12500       17.89       20.74
4     6     1 20.56667       19.96       21.00
5     8     0 15.05000       10.69       18.56
6     8     1 15.40000       15.08       15.72
```